# Setting static IP address in Hana Express Edition

Tags: hana

I have installed at work SAP Hana Express Edition 2.0 in my laptop. It runs on VMware/Suse. I also set up a static IP address so I don't have to change the client connections. This works fine when I'm at work.

I added the following to hosts file:

```
   192.168.1.85    hxehost
```

Problem is that when I take my laptop somewhere else all my client connections time out. I checked the IP address in Suse and it's the one I assigned. How to fix this problem?

If I disconnect the laptop from the Internet, I get the following error:

```
JDBC: Cannot connect to jdbc:sap://192.168.1.85:39013/ [Cannot connect to 
host 192.168.1.85:39013 [No route to host: connect],
```

This is my setup:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How you connect to the virtual machine's IP ports depends on the setup chosen for the VM networking.
The address `192.168.1.85` is part of the `192.168.1.x` network, which is very popular for home-router setup and small LANs. It's very likely that your laptop is part of such a network, when not at work. So when you `ping` the address the laptop uses the network interface that is linked to this network (e.g. your wifi adapter) to look for the host with IP `192.168.1.85`. Whoever host currently got the `85` in your network, it's likely not your virtual machine.

One easy way to avoid this is to setup the virtual machine with `host-only` network. For that you have to configure the network adapter in VMware (or whatever hypervisor you use) to use the host-only network and assign an IP address **in a different subnet** e.g. in `192.168.5.x`. For the HANA client software on your computer, the address to use would, of course, be `192.168.5.85` but it would be stable across all networks your laptop may log into.

Comment: Thanks for the tip on using `host-only`, I also had to assign a new IP address in the same subnet as the VM.